# discord py buttons triggered multiple times

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So im Making a Voice Support Bot in discord py and im stuck on a problem with the Buttons to Close the case or report abuse.

This is the Code where it sends the embed with the Buttons (This works)

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_ui import Button, UI

@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    try:
        if after.channel.id == int("944642625351327784"):
            if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
            notifychannel = bot.get_channel(944642626055979059)
            embed = discord.Embed(title="test")
            notifyembed = await ui.components.send(notifychannel, embed=embed, components=[
                    Button("Close", f"close-{uservoicechannel.id}", "green", emoji="✅"),
                    Button("Abuse!", f"abuse-{uservoicechannel.id}", "red", emoji="️", new_line=False)
                ])
    except:
        pass
```

And this is the Code where it listens to the Button Click:

```py
@bot.listen("on_button")
async def on_button(btn):
    print(btn.component.custom_id)
```

Everything works but when there are 3 Channel open and someone clicks on ONE Button its triggered 3 times.

Is there a way to fix this maybe disable the button with the custom id or some?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who is stuck on the same Problem:

Fixed it with using pycord.